# Clique-or-almost reduction to clique

Tags: reductions, np-hard

I saw the posted question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16325/direct-reduction-from-near-clique-to-clique) about a direct reduction from near-clique to clique.

Clique-or-almost is like near-clique but with the option for a complete clique of size $k$, I mean that perhaps an edge is missing and perhaps not.

I can't figure out how to change the proof in the link to fit to the reduction from Clique-or-almost to Clique.

> $$\text{CLIQUE-or-almost} = \{(G,k) \mid \text{ $G$ contains a $k$-clique with possibly one missing edge}\}.$$

Comment: Can you make the post self-contained by adding a definition of near-Clique? A formal definition of the problem you're considering (Clique-or-almost clique) would also help.

Comment: I added a formal definition for Clique-or-almost. Near-clique is the same but without the work "possibly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G=(V, E)$ is the graph of an instance of CLIQUE-or-almost to CLIQUE,
then you can create a new graph $G'$ as the disjoint union of $G$ with all the graphs $G + e$ for $e \in \binom{V}{2} \setminus E$.

Then $G$ has a clique or an almost-clique on $k$ vertices if and only if $G'$ has a clique on $k$ vertices.

This shows that CLIQUE-or-almost $\le_p$ CLIQUE.
You can also show a polynomial reduction from CLIQUE to CLIQUE-or-almost.

Start with the graph $G=(V,E)$ in the instance of CLIQUE and build a graph $G'$ in which there are two copies $v_1, v_2$ of each vertex $v \in V$ along with the edge $(v_1, v_2)$. For each $(u,v) \in E$ add to $G'$ the four edges $(u_1, v_1), (u_1, v_2), (u_2, v_1), (u_2, v_2)$.

If there is a clique $C$ of size $k$ in $G$ then there is a clique of size $2k$ in $G'$ (consider all the copies of the vertices in $C$).

If there is a clique $C$ of size $2k$ in $G'$ then there is a clique of size at least $k$ in $G$ (consider all the vertices $v \in V$ such that $C$ contains at least one of $v_1$ and $v_2$).

Finally, if there is a clique $C$ minus one edge $(u_i ,v_j)$ of size $2k$ in $G'$, then $C$ cannot contain $v_{3-j}$, as otherwise the edge $(u_i, v_{3-j})$ would be missing too. This means that $C \setminus \{v_j\}$ contains $2(k-1)+1$ vertices. Thus, the set of vertices $w$ such that $C \setminus \{v_j\}$ contains at least one of $w_1$ and $w_2$ is a clique of size at least $k$ in $G$.

Comment: See my comment to @Yuval Filmus,

Comment: Are you fine with a Cook reduction? If so, check if $G = (V,E)$ has a clique, if the answer is "yes" then you are done. If not, for each edge $e$ that is missing from $E$, check if $G + e$ contains a clique. If the answer is "yes" then you found an almost-clique in $G$.
If all the answers are "no", then the answer to your problem is also "no".
If you want a Karp-reduction, take the disjoint union  $G'$ of $G$ with all graphs $G+e$ for $e \not\in E$. There is an almost-clique in $G$ iff there is a clique in $G'$.

Comment: I can't use a Cook reduction, because if there exist a Cook reduction from A to B, that doesn't mean that there must be a Karp reduction from A to B. Am i wrong?

Comment: You are right but I also provided a Karp reduction.

Comment: You are right! thanks! please update your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reduction from CLIQUE to CLIQUE-or-almost.

Let $G$ be an arbitrary graph. Form a new graph $G'$ by adding two new vertices $x,y$ connected to all vertices of $G$, but not to each other. If $G$ contains a $k$-clique, then $G'$ contains a $(k+2)$-clique with a missing edge.

Conversely, suppose that $G'$ contains a $(k+2)$-clique $S$, possibly with a missing edge. If the clique doesn't contain a missing edge, then $S \setminus \{x,y\}$ is a clique of size at least $k$ in $G$. If $x,y \in S$ then the missing edge is $(x,y)$, and again $S \setminus \{x,y\}$ is a $k$-clique of $G$. In the remaining case, $|S \setminus \{x,y\}| \geq k+1$. Remove one vertex from the missing edge to obtain a clique of size at least $k$ in $G$.

---

For a reduction in the other direction, it is well-known that CLIQUE is NP-hard. Since CLIQUE-or-almost is clearly in NP, by definition there is a reduction from CLIQUE-or-almost to CLIQUE. One can construct such a reduction via the proof of the Cook-Levin theorem.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you described a reduction from clique to clique-or-almost. as i mentioned in the post, i am seeking for a "reduction from Clique-or-almost to Clique".

Comment: Clique is known to be NP-hard, so we know that such a reduction exists. There is no reason to construct such a reduction explicitly.

Comment: I know but i need to prove that Clique-or-almost is in NP by showing a direct reduction to Clique.

Comment: You can prove that it's in NP directly. It's much easier.

Comment: i know but again: in the exercise they explicitly asking for a direct reduction...

Comment: Sounds like a silly exercise.

Comment: I agree with you XD